# How to attack Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem if the first element in the superincreasing series is too small?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

In *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography* Jeffrey Hoffstein et al. claim that "It turns out that if $r_1$ is too small, then there are easy attacks, so we must insist that $r_1>2^n$." Here $r_1$ is the first element of the superincreasing series used in the Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem before it is disguised with modular arithmetic and $n$ is the number of elements in the series.  Does anyone have information on how these attacks might work or a basic explanation of why too small $r_1$ is unsafe?

Comment: Presumably if $r_1\leq 2^n$, then brute force attacks are easily done?